# Typo3 Indexed Search Local_Lang path

Tags: typo3, typoscript

i am wondering what TS code is needed to set path to my own indexed search local_lang.
I changed what i needed in pi1/local_lang but i would like to set it to my own so i can have the edited (Croatian in this case) for future projects.

Something like:

```
plugin.tx_indexedsearch.templateFile = fileadmin/search_temp.html
```

but for Local_lang of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with this lines you can overwrite individual translations:

```
    plugin.tx_myPlugin_pi1._LOCAL_LANG.de.key = value; 
    plugin.tx_myPlugin_pi1._LOCAL_LANG.en.key = value;
```

I think that not all extensions supports a complete own localLang file, but not 100% sure.

Answer (score 1):

You could add your translation to the [official Translation Server](http://translation.typo3.org/) . So your translation will be available trough the Translation Modul in TYPO3 Backend.

The croation translation for indexed_search is managed there: http://translation.typo3.org/hr/TYPO3.TYPO3.core.indexed_search/

There is a single-sign-on with typo3.org implemented. So you need an account on [typo3.org](http://typo3.org/my-account/sign-up/) first.

Comment: Thanks for input, i am registered there already and i send lots of translation already on few extensions :)