# Translations in indexed-search with own templates

Tags: typo3-8.x, tx-indexed-search

I'm using Typo3 8.7.11 and the extension indexedSearch 8.7.11 with Fluid-Templates

I created an extension with my own fluid-templates for the search and search-results form.

Now I also want to use my own translations for these templates. So I created the following files in `myTemplateExt/Resources/Private/Language`:

- locallang.xlf (for the default - en - language)
- de.locallang.xlf
- fr.locallang.xlf
- it.locallang.xlf

Alas, the translations are not loaded.

I found out that I can add the whole path to the translations like

```
<f:translate key="LLL:EXT:myTemplateExt/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:sform.submit" />
```

But then only the locallang.xlf file is loaded. All other languages are ignored.

I also tried to add my own variable to the indexed-search TS-setup:

```
plugin.tx_indexedsearch.settings.langfile = EXT:myTemplateExt/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf
```

Which of course fails miserably (most likely because I can't define my own settings-var in TS for another extension?)

Any ideas how I can make the indexed-search extension use my own lang-files?

P.S. I found this suggestion on StackOverflow:

[Typo3 Indexed Search Local_Lang path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15405465/typo3-indexed-search-local-lang-path)

But this is not what I want - I need more flexibility for my templates, as I need to add some more text than just the regular keys that indexed-search provides to them (yeah, customers, you know ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might not be the best solution, but I solved the problem like this:

I set a variable according to the current language:

```
<v:variable.set name="currentLang" value="{v:page.language(languages: 'LLL:EXT:myExt/Resources/Private/Language/de.locallang.xlf,
LLL:EXT:myExt/Resources/Private/Language/en.locallang.xlf,
LLL:EXT:myExt/Resources/Private/Language/fr.locallang.xlf,
LLL:EXT:myExt/Resources/Private/Language/it.locallang.xlf',
 normalWhenNoLanguage: 'LLL:EXT:myExt/Resources/Private/Language/de.locallang.xlf')}" />
```

And then for the translation:

```
<f:form.submit name="search[submitButton]" value="{f:translate(key: '{currentLang}:sform.submit')}" id="tx-indexedsearch-searchbox-button-submit" class="tx-indexedsearch-searchbox-button" />
```

This isn't elegant, but it works...